# ImageMap polygon coordinates shifting to the right in Google Chrome

Tags: html, coordinates, imagemap

I have the image below on my website. For the colored states, the image map coordinates are working as expected. I need to add IL state to my map. I've been trying all sorts of poly coordinates but it seems not to be working. I took a screenshot of what the outline looks like when I click it. I've tried in Chrome and FF. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
<p><img src="/assets/map.jpg" alt="" border="0" usemap="#StateMap" /></p>
<map name="StateMap">  
    <area shape="poly" coords="98,116,124,120,123,132,142,135,136,186,88,178" href="/utah" alt="" />  
    <area shape="poly" coords="88,179,79,188,71,232,106,252,127,254,135,186" href="/arizona" alt="" />    
    <area shape="poly" coords="347,131,368,129,372,140,376,181,369,205,358,205,333,166" href="/illinois" alt="" />
</map>
```

EDIT: Here's the CSS. I took it from Chrome's developer window

CSS inline style (I took it out above without realizing that it might matter):

```
style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); float: none; margin: 0px;"
```

CSS:

```
img{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.span8{
    font-size: 16px;
}
body{
    font-family: 'lato';
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[image: US Map]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include the CSS, maybe you didn't define the positioning correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: That `max-width` in the image is _keelling_ me. How can you have an image map with relative sizes? It will break if the image is resized. I have created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vu59jo4b/) with the picture and your code, and the funny thing is that the only state that is in place is Illinois (but only when the inline styling is removed: http://jsfiddle.net/vu59jo4b/1/). It almost looks like you calculated the coordinates for some states with the padding, and some others without the padding (and there may be some other CSS affecting too). Apart from that, the map works great for me.

Comment: yikes! I didn't even think about the image resizing. That is a concern. Thanks. The problem with a lot of this is that the site was designed to be a content management system, so I'm still discovering how the pieces fit. As for the fiddles, in both cases, I still see IL off to the right (in fact, a little better in the first fiddle), and in both fiddles, UT and AZ are nearly spot-on (more so in the 2nd fiddle though). Btw, I calculated the coordinates using some online calculator (the same one for all three) and I also checked it manually in MS paint (it was close).

Comment: That is strange. I have checked on Chrome only, will look in other browsers later